# How can I remove Facebook Pixel from Facebook - 2019?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pixel

I have 3 facebook pixels on my facebook: one of them is on my personal account and the other 2 live on my business manager account. I have been trying so hard to remove 2 of these pixels since I use only one of them but in vain! I have searched all over google and nobody really addressed this issue, at least regarding the new facebook platform!

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Been there. Unfortunately there is no ACTION in the lower menu. You won't find no X to delete anything. I’ve contacted support and they say IT’S NOT POSSIBLE TO DELETE A PIXEL, only deactivate it by removing the code from the site. This is outrageous.. Although i would reccommend you read this article : https://www.techjunkie.com/delete-facebook-pixel/

Comment: It is insane! They wanna make sure they track your website even after you delete the pixel from your website!

Comment: How would they track anything, if you did not even embed the tracking code any more … makes little sense. Having the pixel still show up in your account dashboard might be a bit annoying perhaps, but that doesn’t mean there’s anything nefarious going on regarding your site.

Comment: After contacting facebook support, I learned that it is not possible to delete your pixel from your account! This is outrageous indeed and does not make any sense!

Comment: Although you cannot delete them, you can remove them from the sites. If you have removed the scripts by hand from the code, but pixels are still visible via developer tools, it might be worth checking CRM settings if you're using one. Some CRM systems like Hubspot can add FB pixel to your site from their side, and removing it is just flicking a switch.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After contacting facebook support, I learned that it is not possible to delete your pixel from your account! This is outrageous indeed and does not make any sense! You can remove them from your site and this would stop data tracking and everything, except for your facebook account would have multiple Pixels that would make it look unorganized...

Comment: This is OUTRAGEOUS indeed! now i'm having an issue, i always get the messsage that i have too many pixels (btw i just have 3, of which i need none) and i can't delete the damn pixel. please how did you succeed to talk with the support ?

Comment: Indeed, even in 2021, facebook has no way to delete a pixel! And if there are unused pixels, they give a warning!
"Pixel that isn't able to optimize for events:
**SQD Taxtech pixel - unused**
Review the event configuration for your pixel as soon as possible so you can optimize for the events you care the most about. To make changes, first verify your domain, then configure your events in Web Event Configurations in Events Manager."

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to delete an existing pixel. However, you can go to "Business Settings" > "Data Sources" > "Pixels" and there remove the connected "Ad Account" this way the pixel won't show up in your list of pixels when creating ads or custom/lookalike audiences!

Additionally, don't forget to remove them from your website as well.

Answer (score 1):

As Christian Rauchenwald said you have to delete the Ad Account connection of the "bad" Pixel here: https://business.facebook.com/settings/pixels/ (Connected Assets section)

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to delete pixel from business manager. You can trash only ad account with pixel.
Step 1. Go to business manager
Step 2. Select Business Account
Step 3. go to data sources
Step 4. select pixel

there is no option to delete sorry for that!